# How to scale the fontsizes using Plots.jl

Tags: plot, julia, plots.jl

is there a way to rescale all the fontsizes  (legend, tickslabels, axislabels…) at once?

Original question from [Filippo Vicentini](https://julialang.slack.com/archives/C8JKM4JQ6/p1568632261001100) on [Slack](https://julialang.slack.com).

Answer (score 17):

Individual font sizes can be controlled with the `titlefontsize`, `tickfontsize`, `legendfontsize`, `tickfontsize`, `guidefontsize` and `legendtitlefontsize` attributes, but I get that this can be quite tedious.
There is also the `thickness_scaling` attribute.

```
plot(rand(10), thickness_scaling = 0.5)
```

However, this also affects the line widths.
The third option is to call

```
Plots.scalefontsizes(α)
```

to scale all font sizes by a factor `α`. This changes the global fontsize defaults for all subsequent plots and can be undone with

```
Plots.scalefontsizes(1 / α)
```

Answer by [Daniel Schwabeneder](https://julialang.slack.com/archives/C8JKM4JQ6/p1568632261001100) on Slack.

Comment: You can also use `Plots.scalefontsizes()` without an argument to reset the font size. ([relevant commit](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/commit/d3b825b49f89f3822da06d3136cee48fba735ca2))