# Change plot window size in Julia notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, ijulia-notebook

I am using Julia notebook and making plots using basic `Plots` package.

A plot looks good, except its entire size.

[image: Plot without adjusting any size]

I can change the plot size and font size of labels individually. But it becomes less readable unless I change the font size and line width for every component.

[image: Plot when I adjust size and xtickfontsize]

So is there a way to change the size of a plot as a whole? I also hope I can change it by default.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57976419/11213215) what you're looking for? Particularly the `Plots.scalefontsize()` function.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your original question in the title, you can change the size of the Plot Window by specifying the `size` attribute as you already are in your code. See here: http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/basics/ for more details.

As pointed out by Rashid, you can use the `scalefontsize` function to scale the font size. You can also scale the thickness by setting the `thickness_scaling` attribute, see here for more details: http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/generated/attributes_plot/

To be clear, there is not currently a unified way to scale a plot in the way you are looking for it right now, it has to be done manually (though it would be great to have this unified scaling). I opened a feature request for this here: https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/3153